# Dropping the first and last row of an RDD with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm reading in a text file using spark with `sc.textFile(fileLocation)` and need to be able to quickly drop the first and last row (they could be a header or trailer). I've found good ways of *returning* the first and last row, but no good one for removing them. Is this possible?

Comment: if they follow a certain schema, you can use filter.

Comment: They don't, which is the purpose of the tool...

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing this would be to `zipWithIndex`, and then filter out the records with indices `0` and `count - 1`:

```
// We're going to perform multiple actions on this RDD,
// so it's usually better to cache it so we don't read the file twice
rdd.cache()

// Unfortunately, we have to count() to be able to identify the last index
val count = rdd.count()
val result = rdd.zipWithIndex().collect {
  case (v, index) if index != 0 && index != count - 1 => v
}
```

Do note that this might be be rather costly in terms of performance (if you cache the RDD - you use up memory; If you don't, you read the RDD twice). So, if you have any way of *identifying* these records based on their *contents* (e.g. if you know all records but these should contain a certain pattern), using `filter` would probably be faster.

Comment: I was just about to update the question with the a possible solution: I use `take(data.count - 1)` and then filter where `row != data.first`. Being fairly ignorant of how spark works under the covers, which solution would be faster? This data will end up in memory either way.

Comment: There's a very significant difference - `take(data.count - 1)` would collect the entire RDD into the _driver_ memory (a single machine!) which, for large RDDs, would cause an OOM; Caching, on the other hand, keeps the RDD _distributed_ and loads its _partitions_ into the memory of the worker nodes (of which there are many, potentially) - so you're much less likely to get OOM and either way would be faster (data won't have to be transmitted to driver). you should only use `take` to collect a relatively small amount of records.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a lighter version:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6), 3)
val partitions = rdd.getNumPartitions
val rddFirstLast = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex { (idx, iter) =>
  if (idx == 0) iter.drop(1)
  else if (idx == partitions - 1) iter.sliding(2).map(_.head)
  else iter
}

scala> rddFirstLast.collect()
res3: Array[Int] = Array(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: Lighter how? Memory or compute?

Comment: Both. Your version would collected the data (memory) and compare each row (compute). This one keeps the data distributed and relies on the external order of the RDD. So there is no comparison performed and data stays distributed.

Comment: I see. Not to start a flame war here, but are there relative merits between your answer and @Tzach Zhohar's

Comment: the advantage of @Tzach Zhohar's solution that it can be applied at any time of the process, (ie after a shuffle), as the order gets captured after `zipWithIndex`. This one should be done straight after a read, as order might change.

Comment: Since OP will be reading a file, the `sliding` part isn't necessary.

Comment: @philantrovert why not?

Comment: This doesn't account for the case where the first and last partitions may be empty

Comment: @puhlen that is true. but that would only be a problem if there are empty files in the folder it reads. Could cater for that, but then it'd need one extra pass to go through the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it, may require an action(count), expected results always and independent to number of partitions.

```
val rddRowCount = rdd.count()
val rddWithIndices = rdd.zipWithIndex()
val filteredRddWithIndices = rddWithIndices.filter(eachRow =>
  if(eachRow._2 == 0) false
  else if(eachRow._2 == rddRowCount - 1) false
  else true
)
val finalRdd = filteredRddWithIndices.map(eachRow => eachRow._1)
```